# mocked methods are not getting executed?

Tags: java, mockito

Here is my source code.

```
public class Config{
  private Long id;
  private ConfigService configService;
  public Config(Long id){
    this.id=id;
  }
  public setConfigService(ConfigService configService){
    this.configService=configService;
  }
  public ConfigService  getConfigService(){
    return configService;
  }
  public void callingService(){
    ManagedElInterface mei = null
    mei=getConfigService().getIdsFromConfigService(getId());
    //...
  }
  private Long getId(){
  return id;
  }
}
```

I mocked

```
mei=getConfigService().getIdsFromConfigService(getId());
```

but i can see null in "mei"

Below is my test class where i used EasyMock for mocking.

```
public class TestConfig{
  @Test
  public void testcallingService{
  Config config=new Config(12345l);
  ConfigService configService =EasyMock.createMock(ConfigService .class);
  config.setConfigService (ConfigService );
  ManagedElInterface mei=new ManagedElInterface();
  //here i mocked 
  EasyMock.expect(configService.
  getIdsFromConfigService(EasyMock.anyLong()))
  .andReturn(mei);
  config.callingService();
  }
}
```

ConfigService class:

```
    public class ConfigService{
      public ManagedElInterface getIdsFromConfigService(Long l){
        //database code
       return new ManagedElInterface();
      }
    }
```

ManagedElInterface class:

```
  public class ManagedElInterface{
     //data
    }
```

Here **ConfigService** is the class having **getIdsFromConfigService(Long l)**.I dont want to execute this methods so i want to mock.
**getConfigService().getIdsFromConfigService(getId());** is returning object of **ManagedElInterface** class so i created object for **ManagedElInterface and returning with my own data**.
Can you give any clue what i'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: where did you mock that?

Comment: All I see for a mock is this: EasyMock.expect(configArchiveManager.
  getMEIObjectByMNEId(EasyMock.anyLong()))
  .andReturn(mei);

Comment: @Stultuske updated

Comment: indeed. And you changed it to code that will never compile, since now you use a non-existing variable called configArchiveManager

Comment: several parts of your code won't compile. not being able to mock seems to be the least of your issues

Comment: @Stultuske Added complete code.

Comment: I can assure you, by first glance: that still won't compile. I managed to get a simpler version of what you're trying to do to work (with JUnit 5, don't know what version you use), I'll post that as an answer.

Comment: 1.10.19 mockito,4.9.0 junit.

Comment: what are you talking about, Mockito? according to your code, you are using EasyMock?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193371/discussion-between-mae-and-stultuske).

Comment: There is no discussion. basically, you can copy paste what I did below (with the updated versions), and alter the test so it meets your requirements. Mockito and EasyMock might both be mocking frameworks, you can't get EasyMock classes from a Mockito dependency. You're mixing up dependencies for some reason.
With my answer below, it should be pretty easy to get your tests to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConfigService:

```
public class ConfigService {    
    public String getId(Long id) {
        return "hardcoded";
    }
}
```

Config

```
public class Config {

    private Long id;
    private ConfigService service;

    public Config(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setConfigService(ConfigService configService){
        this.service=configService;
    }

    public String callingService() {
        String result = this.service.getId(id);
        System.out.println("result = " + result + " for id: " + id);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The tests

```
import org.easymock.EasyMockSupport;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class ConfigTest extends EasyMockSupport {
    // have your testClass extend EasyMockSupport, and use that to create your mock

    private ConfigService service;

    @Test
    public void testCallingService() {
        Config config=new Config(12345l);
        service = createMock(ConfigService.class);
        // as said before, use the createMock method you inherit
        config.setConfigService (service );
        expect(service.getId(12345l)).andReturn("mocked");
        expect(service.getId(17L)).andReturn("smaller");
        replayAll(); // don't forget the replayAll();
        String result = config.callingService();
        assertEquals( "mocked", result);
        Config config2 = new Config(17L);
        config2.setConfigService(service);
        String result2 = config2.callingService();
        assertEquals( "smaller", result2);
        verifyAll(); // to end your test which uses a mock
    }

    // Simple test without the mock to show the difference
    @Test
    public void testNonMocked() {
        Config config = new Config(50L);
        config.setConfigService(new ConfigService());
        String result = config.callingService();
        assertEquals("hardcoded", result);
    }
}
```

The dependencies I used for the tests

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0-M1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0-M1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0-M1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
    <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @mae don't make the changes you need to make in my answer, but in your local code. If you make it in my answer, as you tried to edit it, it would make the test along with it uncompilable and would basically break the example in the answer

Comment: thanks for your patience.Whatever u did is basic thing i can understand but the question is different  ,thats whay  i'm unable to do (there is no completion errors ).

Comment: got the answer.Forget to use replayAll();.Thanks @Stultuske